# Forget Complete navigation history React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, screen

I am building a react native app that involves a payment process and on finishing the transaction a user is navigated to the homepage,the issues is the user can go back to the previous screen  which is not what i want.
I found out this solution that works halfway

```
navigation.replace("MainScreen");
```

since even though it replaces the previous screen it goes back to another previous screen.
Is there a way I can forget the entire navigation after I finish my transaction

navigation Stack

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
  ></Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="MainScreen"
    component={MainScreen}
  ></Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Cart"
    component={Cart}>
  </Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Orders"
    component={Orders}
  ></Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="OrderDetails"
    component={OrderDetails}
  ></Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Checkout"
    component={Checkout}
  ></Stack.Screen>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

i am trying to navigate from checkout to mains screen

Comment: can you share your navigation stack structure?

Comment: @rishikesh_07 see my upated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.
There is a popToTop method in naviagtion 6 that takes you to the first screen of your stack, if that is not the screen you want to be you then simply navigate to the page you want to be immediately. Like so,

```
    navigation.popToTop()
    navigation.navigate('MainScreen')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you finish your workflow, instead of navigating to the `MainScreen`,
which should be something like this:

```
navigation.navigate('MainScreen')
```

try to use this code:

```
navigation.reset( {
      index: 0,
      routes: [{name: 'MainScreen'}]
    })
```

Please note that using this method, there might be a slight delay (depending on how much screens are presented on your navigation stack).

To avoid this lag, it might be better to remove only screens connected with the transaction, but you stated that you want to forget whole stack, so this is the method.

Comment: This had an issue where I was not able to go to the first page/root of the stack. See my updated question for the stack